# Does adding information to this table makes it lose its 3NF

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, normalization

The table below is from a tutorial where the tables are in 3rd normal form. But if I insert information into the table PROJECT as follows:

```
projectCode  projectDescr  customerNo

1            Apples        21

1            Apples        22
```

Didn't I lose the 3NF cos the projectcode and projectdescr ends up repeating since 2 customers could possibly have the same project?

So my question is whether the table in the image below is in 3NF. And does the above problem even exists or I am looking at it wrongly? I am setting up my own table but before that I am trying to get the 3NF understanding right. Please help. Thanks.

The table from the tutorial:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption in the example would be that the relationship between PROJECT and CUSTOMER is many to one. A customer may have multiple projects but each project applies to only one customer. If you want a project to apply to multiple customers, then you need to split out another project_customer table that just contains a project and customer key for each row.

Comment: Based on that, seems eliminating all assumptions will end with lots of tables since almost all 3NF tutorial presents the same issue where one could break the 3NF by populating the tables.

Comment: 'Constraint' is probably a better word than assumption. Inserting duplicate primary keys isn't allowed in practice, so it's more than just assumption, you can't make such an insert. If you remove all restrictions on data then, yes, you are throwing normal forms out the window.

Comment: The relationship between data is important. You can't normalize without defining that.